# Unable to parse date format in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, d3.js, date-format

I'm working with D3 and am trying to parse the following date format

```
2013-06-16T07:00:00+0000
```

I've tried using the following code to parse it properly but it doesn't work:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M+%S").parse;
```

I can't seem to properly decipher the formate in order to parse it. Does anyone know the proper way to write this date format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That format is [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) / [RFC3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt), and is only supported in newer browsers.  See [here](http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html) for a list of browsers that support it natively.

Usually, my recommendation would be to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).  But since you are already using d3, you should look at [their reference for time formatting](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting).

Looking at your string, it appears you just have the format string wrong.  Do this instead:

```
var dt = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z").parse('2013-06-16T07:00:00+0000');
```

Comment: Thanks. Although this is the correct format, a note to others that d3 currently doesn't support %Z for parsing. As a workaround, I split my date on '+' and parsed just using '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'. https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-parse

Comment: ok, but you'll want to make sure that you always have `+0000` and not some other offset, and you should make sure this is treated as UTC and not local time.  If d3 can't do that, then look at moment.js.